# How to get instructions at her address?

Tags: frida

With the help of gidra, I found the function of interest.

```
void __fastcall FUN_gameWhile(int buf?)
```

function address in gidra - `00aad920`

I'm trying to get instructions at this address using frida

```
var moduleData = Process.getModuleByName("main.exe");
var Iprp = moduleData.base.add("0xd920");
console.log(Iprp);
console.log(Instruction.parse(Iprp));
```

looking forward to seeing the instructions : `push ebp`

But I see instructions : `dec ebx` and adress `0x53d920`

If you go to this address in the debugger, there really is this instruction `(dec ebx)`.

I guess it has to do with __fastcall in front of the function name. Why is this happening and how can I get instructions at this address using Frida?

Comment: The function address is 0xaad920 but you add only 0xd920, so the base address configured in Ghidra is 0xAA0000? Get the configured base address here: menu `Window` -> `Memory map` -> `house icon` (Set Image Base). That is the base address you need to substract from the address shown in Ghidra. Afterwards add the base address you got by Frida at run-time e.g. `Module.findBaseAddress("main.exe");`

Comment: I did not know about such functionality of the hydra, so I went the other way. I calculated the difference in addresses and just add this difference to frida. Rather, I will now use your approach. Thank you.